# How to i create blank tpl with only body content in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have the content type called glossary in drupal 7. Some of the pages in the content type will have page.tpl template design. But few pages should not have page.tpl design, It should have only body content of node like ajax tpl.

How do i achieve this? Faster response will be more appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

you can create other .tpl files for example if you want to theme the node with id: 100 ( node/100 ), you can create node--100.tpl.php and there instead of rendering all the content you can print only the body like: `<?php print render($content['body']); ?>`